# Selecting Max Value from Left Join

Tags: sas, max, left-join, proc-sql

I have two tables like below.

```
Profile : ID
Charac : ID, NAME, DATE
```

With the above tables, I am trying to get `NAME` from `Charac` where we have **max** **date**.

I am trying to do a join with `proc sql` by replicating the answer for mysql like below

```
proc sql;
create table ggg as
select profile.ID ,T2.NAME
from Profile
left join 
(   select ID,max(DATE) as max_DATE
    from EDW.CHARAC
    group by ID
) as T1
on fff.ID = EDW.ID
left join EDW.CHARAC as T2
on T2.ID = T1.max_DATE
order by profile.ID DESC;
quit;
```

**Error**

> ERROR: Unresolved reference to table/correlation name EDW.
>
> ERROR: Expression using equals (=) has components that are of different data types.

Comment: `EDW.CHARAC` is this supposed to be `EDW.CHARA`? Also, is `EDW.ID` supposed to reference `Chara`'s id?

Comment: @Compass Sorry for first typo. Yes both tables i.e. Profile and CHARAC have "ID" common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be you intended

```
on T2.ID = T1.max_DATE
```

which is probably source of "components that are of different data types" error

to be:

```
on T2.ID = T1.ID and T2.DATE = T1.max_DATE
```

that, is - joining on IDs at maximum DATE?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `EDW` like that.  You need to join

```
on fff.ID=T1.ID
```

As far as data types, that probably is because `EDW.ID` is undefined and thus numeric by default.